# Open, refresh, remove connection and save as vbscript

Tags: sql-server, excel, vbscript

Can anyone please help me to figure out what is wrong with below VBScripting and how should I correct it?

It meant to

1. Open excel -- works
2. Refresh all data -- works
3. Remove external connection -- Dont work
4. Save as new file without any external connection -- Dont work due to 3rd step otherwise it does

**Solution**:

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.Application.Visible = True
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("file path.xlsx")

oWorkbook.RefreshAll

Do While oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0
     oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count).Delete
Loop

oExcel.Activeworkbook.SaveAs "NewFileName_"& _
MyDateFormat &".xlsx"

oExcel.Activeworkbook.Close
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: In order to really replace the connection it is also necessary to replace the Named range created when the connection in discussion has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Dim oExcel, oWorkbook
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.Application.Visible = True
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("file path.xlsx")

oWorkbook.RefreshAll

'new approach to also delete the named range from Name Manager
Dim strAddr, N
  strAddr = Split(oWorkbook.Connections("connection name").Ranges(1).Address(,,,True), "]")(1)
   oWorkbook.Connections("connection name").Delete
   For Each N In oWorkbook.Names
         If Replace(strAddr, "'", "") = Replace(Mid(N.RefersTo, 2), "'", "") Then
            N.Delete
         End If
   Next
  oWorkbook.SaveAs "NewFileName_" & MyDateFormat & ".xlsx"
  oWorkbook.Close
  oExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for looking into it. I tried your suggestion but it says Line19, Char3, Error:Object doesnt support this property or method:(oWorkbook.Connections("connection name").Address(external:=True), "]")(1) -- is this error due to Iam using VBScripting?

Comment: @Reena Hirani I did not test it in VBScript. Theoretically it should behave similar like in VBA... I modified a little the code. I mean, now. But VBScript is not able to return `msgbox oWorkbook.Connections("Your connection").Ranges(1).Address(external:=True)` as VBA does. It returns `msgbox oWorkbook.Connections("Your connection").Ranges(1).Address` correctly. It is late in my country now and I will close my laptop. Tomorrow I will try understanding how to deal with this 'external' excel specific parameter/constant...

Comment: @Reena Hirani Please, try the updated code. Do not forget to refresh the page (this one)...

Comment: Hi, so after disabling background refresh under workbook connection, I tried your updated code and it worked but the new spreadsheet opens with a warning of trusting the source of the data and also spreadsheet opens in a repair mode and so I lost all my formatting. Maybe is there a way just to copy all sheets and paste into a new spreasheet without losing formating of the report?

Comment: @Reena Hirani I only tried to put in code what I tried reading your question. I observed that when a connection is created, Excel creates also a name (seen in Name Manager), using the same range address. If the connection is created in code and you run it more times. even if the same connection name is kept, some new named ranges are created in Name Manager. Initially I deleted the connection and its equivalent from Name manager, saved the workbook, closed it and it was OK after reopening. Then I put it in code and tried it (in VBA) and nothing wrong happened. Please check it in your case.

Comment: @Reena Hirani I meant, do it manually and see what peculiarities you can see and i can try putting in code the method you declare like being successful. I didn't need such an issue and I tried in the way I explained, only in order to try helping with your code...

Comment: Yes, you helped and thank you very much. Could I ask if I want to use this script for bulk save as - how do I modify my script?